# Inheritance between contracts

Tags: solidity, hardhat, chai

I have a ZombieFactory contract which has a public array, I have another ZombieFeeding contract which inherits from ZombieFactory and I want to display the value of the zombies array defined and populated in ZombieFactory in ZombieFeeding through inheritance

(code from cryptoszombies)

ZombieFactory

```
pragma solidity 0.8.18;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract ZombieFactory is Ownable {

    using SafeMath for uint256;

    event NewZombie(uint zombieId, string name, uint dna);

    uint dnaDigits = 16;
    uint dnaModulus = 10 ** dnaDigits;
    uint cooldownTime = 1 days;

    struct Zombie {
        string name;
        uint dna;
        uint32 level;
        uint32 readyTime;
        uint16 winCount;
        uint16 lossCount;
    }

    Zombie[] public zombies;

    mapping (uint => address) public zombieToOwner;
    mapping (address => uint) public ownerZombieCount;

    function createRandomZombie(string memory _name) public {
        uint randDna = _generateRandomDna(_name);
        randDna = randDna - randDna % 100;
        _createZombie(_name, randDna);
    }

    function _createZombie(string memory _name, uint _dna) internal {
        zombies.push(Zombie(_name, _dna, 1, uint32(block.timestamp + cooldownTime), 0, 0));
        uint256 id = zombies.length - 1;
        zombieToOwner[id] = msg.sender;
        ownerZombieCount[msg.sender] = ownerZombieCount[msg.sender].add(1);
        emit NewZombie(id, _name, _dna);
    }

    function _generateRandomDna(string memory _str) private view returns (uint) {
        uint rand = uint(keccak256(bytes(_str)));
        return rand % dnaModulus;
    }

    function getZombiesByOwner(address _owner) external view returns (Zombie[] memory) {
        Zombie[] memory result = new Zombie[](ownerZombieCount[_owner]);
        uint counter = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < zombies.length; i++) {
            if (zombieToOwner[i] == _owner) {
                Zombie memory zombie = zombies[i];
                result[counter] = zombie;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Code ZombieFeeding :

```
pragma solidity 0.8.18;

import "./ZombieFactory.sol";

abstract contract KittyInterface {
    function getKitty(uint256 _id) external view virtual returns (
        bool isGestating,
        bool isReady,
        uint256 cooldownIndex,
        uint256 nextActionAt,
        uint256 siringWithId,
        uint256 birthTime,
        uint256 matronId,
        uint256 sireId,
        uint256 generation,
        uint256 genes
    );
}

contract ZombieFeeding is ZombieFactory {

    ZombieFactory public zombieFactoryContract;
    KittyInterface public kittyContract;

    function setZombieFactoryAddress(address _address) external onlyOwner {
        zombieFactoryContract = ZombieFactory(_address);
    }

    modifier onlyOwnerOf(uint _zombieId) {
        require(msg.sender == zombieToOwner[_zombieId]);
        _;
    }

    function setKittyContractAddress(address _address) external onlyOwner {
        kittyContract = KittyInterface(_address);
    }

    function _triggerCooldown(Zombie storage _zombie) internal {
        _zombie.readyTime = uint32(block.timestamp + cooldownTime);
    }

    function _isReady(Zombie storage _zombie) internal view returns (bool) {
        return (_zombie.readyTime <= block.timestamp);
    }

    function feedAndMultiply(uint _zombieId, uint _targetDna, string memory _species) internal onlyOwnerOf(_zombieId) {
        Zombie storage myZombie = zombies[_zombieId];
        require(_isReady(myZombie));
        _targetDna = _targetDna % dnaModulus;
        uint newDna = (myZombie.dna + _targetDna) / 2;
        if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_species)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("kitty"))) {
            newDna = newDna - newDna % 100 + 99;
        }
        _createZombie("NoName", newDna);
        _triggerCooldown(myZombie);
    }

    function feedOnKitty(uint _zombieId, uint _kittyId) public {
        uint kittyDna;
        (,,,,,,,,,kittyDna) = kittyContract.getKitty(_kittyId);
        feedAndMultiply(_zombieId, kittyDna, "kitty");
    }

    function getZombiesByOwnerFromFeeding(address _owner) external view returns (Zombie[] memory) {
        Zombie[] memory result = new Zombie[](ownerZombieCount[_owner]);
        uint counter = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < zombies.length; i++) {
            if (zombieToOwner[i] == _owner) {
                Zombie memory zombie = zombies[i];
                result[counter] = zombie;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Code des tests chai avec hardhat :

```
const { assert } = require("chai");
describe("Toto", function () {
    let zombieFactory;
    let zombieHelper;
    let zombieFeeding;
    let owner;

    beforeEach(async function () {
        const ZombieFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("ZombieFactory");
        zombieFactory = await ZombieFactory.deploy();
        await zombieFactory.deployed();

        const ZombieFeeding = await ethers.getContractFactory("ZombieFeeding");
        zombieFeeding = await ZombieFeeding.deploy();
        await zombieFeeding.deployed();
        zombieFeeding.setZombieFactoryAddress(zombieFactory.address);

        const ZombieHelper = await ethers.getContractFactory("ZombieHelper");
        zombieHelper = await ZombieHelper.deploy();
        await zombieHelper.deployed();

        /*const ZombieFeeding = await ethers.getContractFactory("ZombieFeeding");
        zombieFeeding = await ZombieFeeding.deploy(zombieFactory.address);
        await zombieFeeding.deployed();
        await zombieFeeding.setZombieFactoryAddress(zombieFactory.address);

        const ZombieHelper = await ethers.getContractFactory("ZombieHelper");
        zombieHelper = await ZombieHelper.deploy(zombieFeeding.address);
        await zombieHelper.deployed();
        await zombieHelper.setZombieFeedingAddress(zombieFeeding.address);*/

        [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();

    });

    it("should create a zombie and get its info", async function () {
        // Créer un zombie avec la méthode createRandomZombie du contrat ZombieFactory
        const zombieName = "Zombie 1";
        await zombieFactory.connect(owner).createRandomZombie(zombieName);
        // Obtenir les informations sur le zombie créé en appelant la fonction getZombiesInfo du contrat ZombieHelper
        const zombiesInfoFromZombieFactory = await zombieFactory.getZombiesByOwner(owner.address);
        console.log("zombiesInfoFromZombieFactory");
        console.log(zombiesInfoFromZombieFactory);
        const lastZombieInfoFromZombieFactory = zombiesInfoFromZombieFactory[zombiesInfoFromZombieFactory.length - 1];
        assert.equal(lastZombieInfoFromZombieFactory['name'], zombieName);

        /*const zombiesInfofromZombieHelper = await zombieHelper.getZombiesByOwnerFromHelper(owner.address);
        console.log("zombiesInfofromZombieHelper");
        console.log(zombiesInfofromZombieHelper);
        const lastZombieInfoFromZombieHelper = zombiesInfofromZombieHelper[zombiesInfofromZombieHelper.length - 1];
        assert.equal(lastZombieInfoFromZombieHelper['name'], zombieName);*/

        const zombies = await zombieFeeding.getZombiesByOwnerFromFeeding(owner.address);
        console.log("zombies from feeding");
        console.log(zombies);

    });



});
```

Voici le résultat des tests :

Toto
zombiesInfoFromZombieFactory
[
[
'Zombie 1',
BigNumber { value: "8229335091878300" },
1,
1686035752,
0,
0,
name: 'Zombie 1',
dna: BigNumber { value: "8229335091878300" },
level: 1,
readyTime: 1686035752,
winCount: 0,
lossCount: 0
]
]

zombies from feeding
[]
√ should create a zombie and get its info

4 passing (1s)

Done in 2.07s.

> > On voit que le tableau récupéré dans ZombieFeeding est vide ! alors que ce contrat hérite de ZombieFactory !
> > zombies from feeding []

Quelqu'un d'expérimenté pour m'aider svp ?